# Что значит это регулярное выражение?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$INSTALLED = '0';
$val = '$INSTALLED';
$oldval = "$INSTALLED"
$regex = '~\\'.$val.'\s+=\s+\''.$oldval.'\';~is';
```

Две тильды для обозначения начала и конца регулярного выражения. Дальше непонятно, какую функциональность несет слеш, который после первой тильды. Потом непонятно, зачем нужно брать строку в одинарные кавычки после её конкатенации в выражение. Также неясно, зачем нужны две пары одинарных кавычек после конкатенации второй строки. И напоследок, что делает `~is'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Дальше непонятно, какую функциональность несет слеш

Бэкслэш. Он экранирует следующий бэкслэш, поэтому первым символом совпадения должен быть один бэкслэш.

> Потом непонятно, зачем нужно брать строку в одинарные кавычки после её конкатенации в выражение

Если вы про это

```
$oldval = "$INSTALLED"
```

то а) действительно не нужно и б) остутствие точки с запятой после выражения с `$oldval` убьет весь скрипт. Что до

```
$val = '$INSTALLED';
```

до заключенная в одинарные кавычки строка такой и останется. Другими словами:

```
$val . '=' . $oldval === '$INSTALLED=0';
```

> Также неясно, зачем нужны две пары одинарных кавычек после конкатенации второй строки.

Очевидно, по задумке после знака равно должно стоять значение, заключенное в одинарные кавычки, например, это все должно было бы совпасть с

```
\$INSTALLED = '0';
```

Проще говоря, это прям-таки PHP-парсер для одного очень узкозаданного присвоения (правда, непонятно, что там делает бэкслэш).

> И напоследок, что делает ~is

Все, что идет после второго разделителя - это флаги регулярного выражения, i = ignorecase, регистронезависимый поиск, s = PCRE_DOTALL, заставляет метасимвол "точка" совпадать с любыми символами вообще (без использования модификатора точка не совпадет с переводом строки). Подробнее, как всегда, в доках - http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Спасибо, хорошо объяснили. Кстати, вот ещё как это выглядит:
в одном файле функция :

     function write_value_of($var,$oldval,$newval, $file)
    {
     $contents = file_get_contents($file);
     $regex = '~\\'.$var.'\s+=\s+\''.$oldval.'\';~is';
     $contents = preg_replace($regex, "$var = '$newval';", $contents);
     file_put_contents($file, $contents);
    }

в другом вызов:

    write_value_of('$INSTALLED', "$INSTALLED", '1', "config.php");

Есть ли смысл вообще в таком парсинге и замене? Или не самая удачная идея?

Comment: @xinakapu, это редактор конфигурации. В PHP всегда была боль от отсутствия внятной конфигурации, ее пишут на чистом PHP, и читается она нормально, а вот с перезаписью бывают сложности. Я последние сутки пишу простенький yaml-конфигуратор с импортами. В общем, идея терпима только из-за отсутствия внятной сериализации в PHP. Лучше переписать c помощью какого-нибудь symfony/yaml.